# ActionScript - Masking Parent of Dynamic Text Removes Anti-Alias?

Tags: actionscript-3, text, mask, antialiasing

when adding a mask to a parent sprite with a dynamic text field, the text loses anti-aliasing.  how can i maintain the text's anti-alias while still applying a mask to its parent, and subsequently to itself.

the font is embedded, and the text field will be animated so it must also be masked along with its parent.

[image]

```
package
{   
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.text.*;

public class Test extends Sprite
    {
    public function Test()
        {
        //Create Background Canvas
        var canvas:Sprite = new Sprite();
        canvas.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000)
        canvas.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

        //Create Dynamic Text
        var field:TextField = new TextField();
        field.width = 100;
        field.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        field.selectable = false;
        field.text = "Dynamic\nText";

        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.font = "Myriad Pro";
        format.color = 0xFFFFFF;
        format.size = 14;
        field.setTextFormat(format);

        //Add Dynamic Text To Background Canvas
        field.x = canvas.width /2  - field.width / 2;
        field.y = canvas.height / 2 - field.height / 2;
        canvas.addChild(field);

        //Create Mask
        var canvasMask:Shape = new Shape();
        canvasMask.graphics.beginFill(0);
        canvasMask.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100, 100, 50);

        //Add Background Canvas And Mask To Display List
//      canvas.mask = canvasMask;
//      addChild(canvasMask);
        addChild(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this has to do with the way the TextField is cached as a Bitmap when you apply the mask. Actually I was able to reproduce the same behavior simply by toggling the cacheAsBitmap property on the TextField.

Adding these lines seem to solve the problem.

```
    field.embedFonts = true;
    field.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
    //you can adjust the thickness & sharpness if needed
    field.thickness = 200;
```

Comment: ahh, bitmap caching. of course. your solution works well, thanks. but even with adjusting the textfield's thickness and sharpness, the font still isn't as exactly as non bitmap cached font. don't get me wrong, it's very very close and completely acceptable, but i'm just curious. i suppose this is a result of the embedded font trying to emulate its natural vector outline as a bitmap?